# problem with insetting faces

Tags: modeling

i want to inset the face to 1 mt.
actually the face is 20x20.
when i apply it to  mi its insetting like  this 
but i need the result of the face 19 x 19 after insetting
 but im getting like that when i inset by 0.1 but its not correct to the actual diensions

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Object mode, select your object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then select Scale.

This will make sure the **Local** scale of the vertices, match the **Global** scale of the scene.

This probably happened because you scaled your object in Object mode rather than in Edit mode.

Comment: thanks dude working